# Flash vs. After effect vs. premiere

Tags: flash, after-effects, adobe-premiere

I'm very confused about the differences between Flash, After effect and Premiere
What is the usage of each program and when i need to use which one of them?

if any one can help I will be thankful

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this question related to a project you have to start and you don't know which software to use? Maybe you can describe the project so the community can answer more detailed.

Comment: yes, I have to start project , I was expect that I should learn flash for it , but after that i think i will not be able to do that with flash only , the project idea will be some characters i will draw them in adobe illustrator then i have to take them to flash and animate them , but i will need a lot of effects that doesn't exist in flash , so what should i use?

Comment: So use After Effects. AE has a built-in script engine which is very strong. Try Google: [www.tutorialsphere.com/tutorials/after-effects/text-effects](http://www.tutorialsphere.com/tutorials/after-effects/text-effects)

Comment: decide what you want to do first, then pick the right tool. For web animation using vector graphics use Flash. While Flash can handle bitmaps too, the it's really made for vectors, and After Effects will provide you more mature tools for handling bitmaps, better timeline tools, etc. You would use Premiere to edit filmed footage mainly (cut/paste/fade/etc.) and less for animation from scratch. HTH

Comment: Although Flash can import illustrator Files, and you have some Bone tools, give After Effects a go too(since it can import Illustrator files) and see if the tools there suit your task better

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Taken from wikipedia:

> **Adobe Premiere Pro** is a real-time, timeline based proprietary video editing software application.

(my note: something along the Windows Movie Maker lines but I've never used it so this statement may be a bit off)

> **Adobe Flash** (formerly Macromedia Flash) is a multimedia platform used to add animation, video, and interactivity to web pages. Flash is frequently used for advertisements and games. More recently, it has been positioned as a tool for "Rich Internet Applications" ("RIAs").

and:

> **Adobe After Effects** is a digital motion graphics and compositing software published by Adobe Systems. Its main purpose is for film and video post-production: combining multiple video sources in various ways (compositing), correcting brightness, color, and unwanted camera motion, adding visual effects, and many similar tasks.

Comment: Premiere has the ability to layer video files and/or After effects projects. Simply put: After Effects is Photoshop on a timeline

Comment: @Roger Photoshop extended has a timeline :P

Answer (score 0):

I've used all 3 of these softwares , though all 3 share quite many features but for practical purpose all 3 have diff utilities:

> **Flash**-Used for basic  **2D**  animation(cartoons and stuff). Used more in web designing, flash features on your web page using action-scripting, sketches and animations. Lesser utility in video making , motion graphics
>
> **AE**- After Effects, as the name suggests is used to edit your "video footages" post shooting. You can add a whole bunch of effects and add realism to your videos. Another aspect of this is motion graphics. What it means is creating whole animations within ae only using permutations of effects and brainstorming them.

Note: AE basically relies on other softwares like photoshop, flash , or footages, pics and enhances them or edits them or adds something to them. Where as flash makes animates from scratch, you have to draw stuff and make it animate plus animation on click(examples on various websites) using action scripting in flash only (or flex) but not in ae.

> **Premier Pro**: its basically the video editting software where you can edit your final video on timeline, adjust audio u want to have in it , allign em comfortably. AE can do almost whole of basic premier stuff but premier provides more flexibility.

Answer (score -2):

Use after effect for short video, after this is the best tool for amazing effects (like the name of it) :) , premier is good for long movies,

After effects:
Not real time - thats mean it can take a lot of time to render your work.
Better with effects - more options than premier.

Premier:
Real time - you can play any video you want in 1 second
Nice effects but not like after.

I'm not familiar with Flash so i'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

**Adobe Premiere.** Full-fledged video editing, creation, and production. Any format, size, or creative approach can be done here.

**Adobe After Effects.** This is the specialized editing product to create specific effects (animations, text effects, short videos). It's strength in in complete control on a frame-by-frame basis with an immense range of motion and graphical options. Use these effects to import into a Premiere video or in any other platform.

**Adobe Flash** (formerly Macromedia Flash) is a multimedia platform used to add animation, video, and interactivity to web pages.